# radiobuttons in WPF and Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight

Can radiobuttons be set to change between checked and unchecked when being clicked? Do I need to write a special event for every single button to make it happen or just set some simple properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Radio buttons will handle checking and unchecking themselves, based on their grouping. Radio buttons are grouped by parent control and the [GroupName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.groupname.aspx) property.

For example, the following represents two distinct groups of radio options.

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Content="Radio 1" />
    <RadioButton Content="Radio 2" />
    <RadioButton Content="Radio 3" />
    <RadioButton Content="Radio 4" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Content="Radio 5" />
    <RadioButton Content="Radio 6" />
    <RadioButton Content="Radio 7" />
    <RadioButton Content="Radio 8" />
</StackPanel>
```

But using the `GroupName` property, we could, for example, have three groups:

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Group1" Content="Radio 1" />
    <RadioButton GroupName="Group2" Content="Radio 2" />
    <RadioButton GroupName="Group1" Content="Radio 3" />
    <RadioButton GroupName="Group2" Content="Radio 4" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Content="Radio 5" />
    <RadioButton Content="Radio 6" />
    <RadioButton Content="Radio 7" />
    <RadioButton Content="Radio 8" />
</StackPanel>
```

In the above code, the 1st and 3rd radio are grouped independently of the 2nd and 4th.